# Build static site once and deploy on multiple hosts

Tags: javascript, static-site, docusaurus

I want to build my documentation for being hosted in multiple offline environments, hosted on docker containers. This requires following key features in static site generator,

- Use all resources (js / css), hosted locally with static html files.
- Configure `url` and `baseUrl` at deployment time (when docker container is started).

These two configurations can help achieve, build once deploy anywhere, and in an offline environment.

Two questions,

- How to set url at deploy time?
- How to set all resources to be hosted locally?

Comment: Good for you. So, what's the problem here?

Comment: How can do it? Not available in documentation.

Comment: Two questions,
* How to set url at deploy time?
* How to set all resources to be hosted locally?

Answer (score 0):

You may think you should write url in `https://{{ baseUrl }}/a.js`, and set baseUrl in compile options, actually you don't need to do so.

Just use the relative path, suggest you have a image tag

- `<img src="somephoto.jpg" />` means file is located in the same directory as the current page
- `<img src="../somephoto.jpg" />` means file is located in the upper directory to the current page
- `<img src="/somephoto.jpg" />` means file is located in the root of the website

Comment: The documentation suggests that you will have to do it when you run `npm run build` - https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/publishing

Comment: @HassanFarid Sorry I didn't notice the problem is about docusaurus, and I never use it before. As docusaurus build your files into static website files, which means no dynamic content exist in the build result. But maybe this is a solution, you can set the `url` field of `siteConfig` in the https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/publishing to `process.env.SITE_URL`, then add `ENV SITE_URL https://your.domain.name` to the Dockerfile, and make the `npm run build` happens in docker image building.

Comment: I want to achieve, build once & deploy everywhere. There has to be some HTML / JS file, storing this variable and reloading each time. So that we can override this place at the time container is started.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write a custom script the overwrites the `siteConfig.js` in it. A high level flow of how this would happen:

- Run script that replaces URL within `siteConfig.js` to host 1 (`replace1.js`)
- Run deploy script.
- Run script that replaces URL within `siteConfig.js` to host 2 (`replace2.js`)
- Run deploy script.

In `package.json`, add a line into the `scripts` portion:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "deploy-multiple": "./replace1.js && docusaurus-build && ./replace2.js && docusaurus-build",
  ...
}
```